# Pre-selecting the category for a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I have a custom post type that has 6 available categories. The categories are used as column headings in a table with their corresponding posts in that column. I want to be able to click on the heading (category name) which will be an anchor tag and open the add new post page in the admin area with the category selected. Does anyone have any ideas on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my exemple, "CPT" stands for the slug of your custom post type.

## First step :

Using the link of "create new CPT" to add the information of category. for exemple the result would look like http://server/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=CPT&category=potatoes

## Second step :

Using the hook `save_post_CPT` to preset the category. it would be something like that :

```
add_action("save_post_CPT", function ($post_ID, $post, $update) {

    if ($update) {
        // it's not a new object
        return;
    }

    if (!isset($_GET["category"])) {
        return;
    }

    // setting the category
    wp_set_object_terms($post_ID, $_GET["category"], "category", TRUE);


}, 10, 3);
```